# Normal Basis Theorem and Regular Representation of $S_3$

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, galois-theory

Right now I'm looking at a number field $E/\Bbb{Q}$ (that is Galois) with Galois group $S_3$ and defining polynomial $p(x)$. I've miraculously managed to find an integral basis in terms of a primitive element $\mathcal{A}=\{\alpha^5,\ldots, \alpha,1\}$ and I have explicit vectors in this $\mathcal{A}$-basis representing the roots of $p$. I've also got the generating transposition $\tau$ and $3$-cycle $\sigma$ for the Galois group $G=\operatorname{Gal}(E/\Bbb{Q}) = S_3$.

What I'm wanting to do from here is find a vector $v$ in this $\mathcal{A}$-basis and a representation $\rho: S_3 \rightarrow \operatorname{SL}^{\pm}(6,\Bbb{Z})$ (coming from the Galois action on the roots) so that the $\rho(S_3)$-orbit of $v$ is a linearly independent set. It seems that I'm butting up against the Normal Basis Theorem and a regular representation of $S_3$, but my representation theory knowledge is not at all strong enough to figure out how to piece this information together.

I had initially hoped that I could make some progress by sheer force, but it seems on the surface that I have *way too many* degrees of freedom in my choice of representation (maybe 8-10 for each of $\tau$ and $\sigma$) to make that worthwhile.

Is there anything I can say definitively that can simplify my search a bit? For example, I know that $\rho(\sigma)$ must have $3^{\text{rd}}$ roots of unity as eigenvalues; can I say anything about which ones should appear and their multiplicity (e.g. "$\rho(\sigma)$ should have eigenvalues $1$, $\zeta_3$, and $\zeta_3^2$ each with multiplicity $2$")?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm happy to provide any of the specifics for my construction if it's useful.

EDIT: Because it was suggested I do so, the roots $\beta_i$ for $p(x)$ have the following vector forms in the ordered $\mathcal{A}$-basis above: $\beta_1=(0,0,0,0,1,0)$, $\beta_2=(0,0,0,0,-1,1)$, $\beta_3=(1,-2,-4,6,4,-2)$, $\beta_4 = (1,-3,-2,8,1,-2)$, $\beta_5 =(-1,3,2,-8,-1,3)$, $\beta_6 = (-1,2,4,-6,-4,3)$.

The Galois group is generated by the transposition $\tau = (\beta_1 \beta_2)(\beta_3 \beta_6)(\beta_4 \beta_5)$ and the $3$-cycle $\sigma= (\beta_1 \beta_3 \beta_4)(\beta_2 \beta_6 \beta_5)$

Comment: $\rho(\sigma)$ will definitely have $1$ as an eigenvalue of multiplicity two. This is because basic Galois correspondence says that the fixed field of $\rho$ is 2-dimensional extension field of $\Bbb{Q}$. Similarly $\rho(\tau)$ has eigenvalue $+1$ with multiplicity three (and $-1$ has multiplicity three as well). The role of $\zeta_3, \zeta_3^2$ as eigenvalues of $\rho(\sigma)$ is less clear. They definitely are eigenvalues of the matrix (because they are there with the regular representation of $S_3$), but they won't have eigenvectors in $E$ unless, per chance, $\zeta_3\in E$. Anyway, +1.

Comment: You'll have to give the specifics of your construction if you hope to get an answer. Also, do you not mean to consider $\rho$ the representation given by the action of the Galois group on the integers in your extension? We aren't really supposed to be guessing $\rho$, are we? (Or else: what do you mean by a "vector $v$ in this $\mathcal{A}$-basis"?)

Comment: @Stephen, I apologize for not being clear, yes, this should be the representation given by the Galois action on the roots in the $\mathcal{A}$-basis. I have edited my original post to include some of the specifics.